# How is out-of-order instruction execution related to superscalar execution?

Tags: operating-systems, parallel-computing

How is out-of-order instruction execution related to superscalar execution?

How is data hazard detection and handling affected by superscalar execution?

Comment: Out-of-order execution is typically not worth implementing (in terms of power/performance/area tradeoffs) outside of superscalar execution. Checking for operand availability is more complex when more operands can be produced each cycle. (Note: a scalar pipeline can also produce multiple results per cycle when different operations have different latencies.) Superscalar execution also typically involves structural hazards even when all operations are fully pipelined (but that is a scheduling issue distinct from operand availability/"data hazard").

Answer (score 1):

Superscalar execution means that some instructions execute simultaneously.  Since the instructions under superscalar execution aren't executing in-order, supserscalar execution is one form of out-of-order execution.